# Arithmetic game with four numbers to get a value of $10$

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

So there's a small game where when we see a four digit number somewhere in public, my friends and I would try to form the value of ten using these four digits with only basic operations.
E.g.
If we see a four-digit number: $5829$

a possible way is to do:
$$9 + 5 - 8 
\div 2 = 10$$

When I say basic I mean operations only include "$+,\div,-,\times"$ and the digits can be used in any order as done above.

Are there any sufficient conditions to guarantee that a string of numbers can attain a value of $10$? How many solutions are there?

Comment: Are you looking for formal solutions of a number like $\overline{xyzt}$ or how many different ways we can get $10$?

Comment: are parentheses allowed ? if so you can make one number into possibly 6 different answers.

Comment: oh and with rearrangement of the digits, like in the example, there's only about 375 unique 4 digit numbers .

Comment: Must all digits be used ? Otherwise "$8+2$" would be an easier way in the example.

Comment: are leading 0's allowed etc. there's tons that haven't been verified.

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın Both, I'm interested to see what conditions on $x,y,z,t$ would allow it to be formed to make $10$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give enough conditions: All digits are to be used and no parentheses, and usually when my friends and I play this game, we count solutions to be the same by commutativity so: $0+0+1+9= 10$ is same solution as $1+9+0+0 =10$. Sorry. I was mainly interested if there were any conditions on the digits (maybe something like the product of digits must exceed something as a necessary condition).

Comment: Perhaps we might check how many solutions are there for $x+y+z+t=10$ (linear) when $x,y,z,t\leq9$ and $\geq0$

Comment: Are you familiar with The method stars and bars

Comment: And also $x\geq1$

Comment: This of course is for the addition part, for the rest I don't have an idea (at least for now) (sorry for sharing these comments on a row)

Comment: okay turns out there's a lot more than 375 but it was a minimum as it was 9000/ 24 ( number of 4 digit numbers without leading 0 divided by number of ways to rearrange 4 distinct digits). `my(a=[]);for(x=1000,9999,if(setminus([vecsort(eval(Vec(Str(x))))],a)==[vecsort(eval(Vec(Str(x))))],a=concat(a,[vecsort(eval(Vec(Str(x))))])));a`  gives me  about 2286 and there's 64 possible selections of 3 operations with repetitions allowed. the good part is we can eliminate a lot of those already anyways I'll do a bit of math and see.

Comment: that was counting repeats apparently even though I thought I counted them out 714 still though. times by 64 is 45696. of which about 22 can easily be found as partitions of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $715$ ways to select $4$ digits when repetitions are allowed. I made a program to run through all combinations of digits and operators and the result was that there are $439$ digit selections which have at least one solution. The complete list is a bit big to post here, so I'm just including a snippet from the start and one from the end.

[image]

[image]